# Avoid using extra variable for storing reference in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm already using `react es6` but still in this case, I don't know how to avoid using that for `this`:

```
const that = this;

UploadApi.exec(file).then(data => {
    that.setState({ loading : false});
});
```

Comment: (data) => { this }  isn't working?

Comment: In this example, you can literally just use `this` where you currently have `that`.

Answer (score 6):

In this example, you are already using `arrow function`, so storing the `reference` in a separate variable is not required. You can directly use `this` keyword like this:

```
//const that = this;

UploadApi.exec(file).then(data => {
    this.setState({ loading : false});
});
```

Storing the `reference` in a separate variable required, when you use `callback method` like this:

```
const that = this;

UploadApi.exec(file).then(function(data){
    that.setState({ loading : false});
});
```

But, you can avoid the extra variable by using `.bind(this)` with `callback method`, like this:

```
//const that = this;

UploadApi.exec(file).then(function(data){
    this.setState({ loading : false});
}.bind(this));
```

Check this answer for complete detail, **[arrow function vs  function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/5185595)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create yout UploadApi.exec that way so that after transpiling your javascript get created accordingly..like below

**In you UploadApi**

```
exec=(file:any):Q.Promise=>{

}
```

and then use it like below

```
UploadApi.exec(file).then(data => {
    this.setState({ loading : false});
});
```